# Load/Get 3d models from the web using Kudan SDK & unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, kudan

Is it possible to load 3D models dynamically / from the web (cloud), using Kudan SDK and Unity?

I want to make an app, which uses SLAM tracking & user can load products dynamically from the web? I have a grid of 3D models the user can click on to augment on screen.

Because if I don't do this? I will have to update the app on the app store in order to give my users new 3D products/models right?

Comment: Kudan doesn't interfere with the way Unity imports or displays models, so that shouldn't be an issue. Just download them like you would in any other Unity project. The only extra thing you have to do is make the model a child of the relevant driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Unity tool to download assets from the web: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DownloadingAssetBundles.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!